# Call one class function in another class

Tags: c++, class

I'm having troubles with classes. I have a class that generates random numbers, and I want to use this random number generator in another class to create a Powerball simulator.

This is my .cpp file for the random number generator:

```
#include "RandomNumber.h"

#include <random>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

RandomNumber::RandomNumber( int min, int max,
                           bool minInclusive, bool maxInclusive )
: mMinimum( min ), mMaximum( max )
{
    if (mMinimum > mMaximum)
    {
        swap( mMinimum, mMaximum );
    }
    if (!minInclusive)
    {
        mMinimum++;
    }
    if (!maxInclusive)
    {
        mMaximum--;
    }
}

int RandomNumber::random( )
{
    static random_device rd;
    static mt19937 generator(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> distro( mMinimum, mMaximum );

    return( distro( generator ) );
}
```

This is my header file for the random number generator:

```
#ifndef RandomNumber_h
#define RandomNumber_h


#include <stdio.h>


class RandomNumber
{
public:
    RandomNumber( int min, int max, bool minInclusive = true, bool maxInclusive= true );

    // supply a number between min and max inclusive
    int random( );
private:
    int  mMinimum, mMaximum;
};

#endif /* RandomNumbers_h */
```

I wanted to call the member function in another class called PowerballLottery and store the 6 values if they're within the appropriate range, I tried to use

```
RandomNumber.random( 1, 69 )
```

and

```
RandomNumber::random( 1, 69 )
```

but neither worked. I'm wondering what is the correct syntax. 
Thank you so much for reading this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a member function you need to instantiate the class.

```
RandomNumber randNum(1, 69);
int newRandomNumber = randNum.random();
```

Comment: True, but in this context, it would make more sense for `random(...)` to just be static member function of `PowerballTicket`. If you need to create dummy instances just to use a method, it is a sign that some `static` action is in order...

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! If I want to generate a random number within another range in the same function, do I just call RandomNumber randNum (1, 23); like this? Or do I need a new instance?

Comment: @Yvonne Yes, you'll need a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

The function signature of the `random` function is:

`int RandomNumber::random();`

This returns an `int` and does not take any parameters. Therefore calling `random(1, 69)` is wrong.

Furthermore, the `random` function isn't `static`. Therefore calling `RandomNumber::random(1, 69)` is wrong (also because it doesn't accept any parameters).

In order to call the `random` function you need to instantiate an object and then call the function using the object instance. For example:

```
RandomNumber prng(1, 69);
prng.random();
```

Answer (score 0):

`RandomNumber` is the name of a class, not an instance, and `random` is a non-static member function. To call `random` as it currently is, you would have to create an instance of `RandomNumber`.

```
RandomNumber rn(/*...args...*/);
rn.random();

//or

RandomNumber(/*...args...*/).random();
```

You could instead make `random` a static member function (or just not a member at all) that takes the constructor parameters as arguments instead.

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget to add

```
#include "RandomNumber.h"
```

to the top of your PowerBall.cpp. Otherwise PowerBall won't know what RandomNumber is!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that since `random()` is a member function of `RandomNumber` and so it can only be called when you instantiate an instance of that class, using the constructor to make an actual object. If you don't really need a specific instance of that class (which it looks like you don't) you can make the function static:

```
static int random();
```

This way it can be called from other classes or main code (as long as `Random.h` is included) just by using `RandomNumber::random()`, because static member functions *don't depend on specific instances of a class*. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Essentially, a static doesn't have the implicit parameter `this`, a pointer to the instance of the object that a regular member function is called on:

```
x.useSomeMethod(); // then inside the call of useSomeMethod(), *this == x
```

However, for your application, the `RandomNumber` class doesn't seem like it needs to be its own class at all. What you can do if you want to use it in `PowerballTicket`, but not make it available to the code that uses that class, is to make `random()` a *private* member function of `PowerballTicket`, and this can also be static since (I'm assuming) it doesn't care what instance of `PowerballTicket` it is being used inside:

```
class PowerballTicket{
public:
    PowerballTicket(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6);
    int getBall1();
    int getBall2();
    int getBall3();
    int getBall4();
    int getBall5();
    int getPowerball();
private:
    static int random(int min, int max, bool minInclusive = true, bool maxInclusive = true);
    int mBall1;
    int mBall2;
    int mBall3;
    int mBall4;
    int mBall5;
    int mPowerball;
};
```

But I'm not sure where you are actually planning on calling `random()` from the code you gave, so you may want to modify this as needed.